# Comparison of $L^2$ and $L^1$ norms for functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

In the context of Lebesgue Integrals, I have came across $L^2$ as the set of measurable functions $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that have Lebesgue integrable squares - that is $x \to  |f(x)|^2$ is Lebesgue integrable.

I have also been introduced to the concepts of the norms:

$$\lVert f\rVert_2 = \left( \int_a^b |f(x)|^2 dx \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

$$\lVert f\rVert_1 =  \int_a^b |f(x)| dx$$

An exercise is asking whether it is true that for every $f \in L^2$, there exists some constant $C \in (0, \infty)$ such that $\lVert f \rVert_1 \leq C\lVert f \rVert _2$, and also whether the converse is true.

I'm very stuck on how to approach this... It seems very intuitive but I am struggling on how to begin a rigorous proof of this.

Any tips or advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the inequality is given by Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$ \|f\|_{L^1} = \int_a^b |f(x)|\, dx \le \left(\int_a^b |f(x)|^2\, dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_a^b \, dx\right)^{1/2} = \sqrt{b - a}\|f\|_{L^2}. $$

Comment: Note that the converse is not true. Hint: Try to play around with $f(x) = 1/x^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure how to proceed with this style of counterexample, all values of $a,b,\alpha$ I have tried lead to numerical answers to which a constant may give our inequality for... Does it involve navigating the discontinuity at $x=0$?

Comment: @2307 Correct. I'm thinking about $\int_0^1 1/x^{\alpha}\, dx$, and this is usually what I play around with whenever I forget about inclusions of $L^p$ spaces (or other function spaces such as Sobolev spaces).

Comment: Sorry to keep adding to this chain... Does it suffice to show that the $L^1$ norm is finite, and the $L^2$ norm is divergent to positive infinity? Is this allowed, or must the $L^2$ norm converge to a finite number?

Comment: @2307 Yes, that would be mean you just found a function $f$ that doesn't satisfy $\|f\|_{L^2}\le C\|f\|_{L^1}$ for any $C > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try using the Hölder inequality for integrals on the function $f\cdot 1$.

In general this will not be true. It is of great importance that your measure space (here: $[a,b]$) has finite measure. Then the $L^p$ spaces fit nicely into each other, i.e. $L^q\subseteq L^p$ whenever $p\le q$ (cf. in the section "embeddings" of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces_and_Lebesgue_integrals for a general solution).

Comment: Thank you for the insight of how measure plays a role here - very interesting read indeed!